# Do prisoners ever finish their sentence and get released?

Tags: prison-architect

So when you click on a prisoner, it will show his sentence, but it's all in years. Does a year equate to an in-game day, or if a sentence if 1 year then the prisoner literally stays for 365 days?

Comment: I sure hope they do, because I hate it when people don't finish their

Comment: ... sandwiches?

Comment: @Tacroy Funnily enough, there also is a bug that prevents prisoners from finishing their dishes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the Alpha 11 release notes, this is now possible:

> **Prisoners now count down their remaining sentence whilst in your jail.**
>   Once they have served their full jail term they are automatically released.
>   They will walk to the exit and be allowed to leave by your guards.
>   Their nameplate will flash "RELEASED"
>   NOTE: We count down sentences at an accelerated rate - otherwise nobody would ever be released
>   NOTE: We do not yet support early release due to Parole

Therefore, prisoners will now be released once they have served their time - and they will even serve their time a little faster right now. This is due to the lack of a management feature to reduce sentences (as in: Parole, or other ways of releasing them early).

Comment: As of [alpha 29](http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Alpha_29) parole has been added, prisoners are now eligible for parole at 50% and 75% through their sentence. [Alpha 30](http://devwiki.introversion.co.uk/pa/index.php/Alpha_30) tweaked the way the parole system works a little.